# How add user with same privileges?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

There is a database owner, I need to add another user with the same privileges. With rights to update/delete/alter, etc.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can create an user and add all privileges trough grant command or
you can just create a role and grant all privileges your role have to the new created role

```
`GRANT A TO B;`
```

It will grant all right of role A to B.

If A is a superuser, you also need: ALTER USER B WITH SUPERUSER;

reference [link1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-roles-and-manage-grant-permissions-in-postgresql-on-a-vps--2) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591557/how-to-create-duplicate-role-of-a-user-in-postgres)

Comment: The only cons are that this way you cannot drop A without B losing the privileges, there are other attributes besides superuser, and B can now impersonate A.

Comment: You also can't drop A without reassigning his ownerships some other user, so that may nt be such a big problem.